# Send model field value to javascript variable

Tags: javascript, django

In django is it possible to communicate with javascript in order to handle variables?

I want to get a field value from one of my model instances and then save it in a javascript string variable, is it possible to do this? The variable must be in the global scope.

Comment: Communicate how? Setting it in a template - sure thats easy, communicate via ajax - not without writing lots of code.

Comment: I just want a simple way to get the value of a field from a model instance and then store it in a javascript variable.

Comment: Yeah, you said that. How do you want to get it the javascript is what I'm asking? What options are they, what have you tried?

Comment: I'm not sure of the available methods of getting it, but I did google and found nothing that was related to my problem. Okay, I have a DetailView, in this DetailView, I want to store the "name" of the instance the DetailView is displaying, in a javascript variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to add it to whatever template you are using like so:

```
<script>
   var my_javascript_var = "{{ my_model.my_attribute }}";
</script>
```

However this requires setting `my_model` (or some other variable) in the context for your template when it is rendered.

Comment: I didn't know you could use inline scrips to store variables, thanks!